# search specific numbers in mysql using regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I've to search a DB table (mysql) for specific rows based on two columns. First column contains a group of numbers separated by comma.
e.g.

## First column

row 1: 1,5,23,19

row 2: 10

row 3: 29,15,30

Second column contains only one number
e.g.

## Second column

row 1: 2

row 2: 23

row 3: 2

Users provide me specific numbers for both of these columns

e.g.

## Input

$column1: 1

$column2: 2

If i use following command

## Command 1

```
$sql = "SELECT field 1, field2... from table a WHERE (a.first_column LIKE '%".$column1."%') AND (a.second_column = ".$column2.")";
```

to search for this example, it gives both row 1 and row 3 both, which is not correct.

## Output 1

### First column

```
row 1: 1,5,23,19 //This is right
row 3: 29,15,30 // This is wrong
```

I understand it matches all rows containing "1". But, *the result should be* **only row 1** in this example.

Using

## Command 2

```
$sql = "SELECT field 1, field2... from table a WHERE (a.first_column = ".$column1.") AND (a.second_column = ".$column2.")";
```

gives null results.

I tried using regex with some help from mysql documentation(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html). I tried to match the rows, where $column1 variable is *not* preceded or followed by any other number. This way, only "1" will be matched, not "15".

## Command 3

```
$sql = "SELECT field 1, field2... from table a WHERE (a.first_column REGEXP '/^(?<![1-9][0-9])".$column1."*(?![1-9][0-9])$/') AND (a.second_column = ".$column2.")";
```

But, it's giving errors. The sql command gets limited at

```
$sql = "SELECT field 1, field2... from table a WHERE (a.first_column REGEXP '/^(?<";
```

and does not consider command after that.

I'm a newbie to php/mysql and don't know regex. I've never used it earlier. I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution. Where am I going wrong? Is there a better / correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you absolutely have to break all the rules of normalization and good database design, and store values in a comma separated list, then consider using [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)..... and it will still always be bad performance

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkBaker, find_in_set() seems to work right now. I understand it will be bad performance, but current DB is a legacy one. I can't change it for this prototype version, but plan to do so in next version. Could you provide your recommendation for that? Will greatly appreciate your inputs. Thanks again